# Exception is thrown during asyncTask execution: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have been looking everywhere in order to understand why my function onPostExecute is never called, so I'm not getting my result String and the app crushes!
Here is the code of the AsyncTask:

```
public class HttpAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
private String Json;
private int response;
private String auth;
private String name;
private AsyncResponse delegate=null;

public HttpAsync(AsyncResponse response, String Json){
    this.Json=Json;
    this.delegate=response;

}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://192.168.0.141:8080/ProgettoProva/AndroidApp");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json, charset=UTF-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/json");
        conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(Json.getBytes().length);
        OutputStream writer = conn.getOutputStream();
        writer.write(Json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        writer.close();

        response=conn.getResponseCode();
        if(response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            auth = "authorized";
           BufferedReader read =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer buf= new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while((line=read.readLine())!=null){
                buf.append(line);
            }
            read.close();
            GsonBuilder builder=new GsonBuilder();
            builder.registerTypeAdapter(String.class,new DataDeserializer());
            Gson gson=builder.create();
            name = gson.fromJson(buf.toString(), String.class);

        }
        else if(response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            auth = "not authorized";
        }
        else if(response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED) {
            auth = "registrato";
        }
        else if(response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CONFLICT){
            auth="gia  presente";
        }

        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("ERRORE", e.getMessage());
    }
    Log.d("STRINGA INVIATA: ", name+"/"+auth);
    return name+"/"+auth;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    Log.d("ONPOSTEXECUTED:", result);
    delegate.returnFinish(result);

}
```

And here is the part of code of the main_activity where I execute the asynctask:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           email = textEmail.getText().toString();
           password = textPass.getText().toString();
           name=textName.getText().toString();
           if(value==1) {
               if (email.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "campi vuoti", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   return;
               }
           }else if(value==2){
               if (email.equals("") || password.equals("") || name.equals("")) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "campi vuoti", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                   return;
               }
           }
           finalJson = createJfile();
         //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json:" + finalJson, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           connection= new HttpAsync(Log_in.this,finalJson);
            connection.execute();
               get=auth.split("/");
               getname=get[0];
               auth=get[1];
```

there is an exception in log:

```
01-13 10:57:32.829 31566-31566/com.example.stage.drawlayoutproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.stage.drawlayoutproject, PID: 31566
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.example.stage.drawlayoutproject.Log_in$1.onClick(Log_in.java:87)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21174)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6862)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Actually It just does print the log at the end of the doInBackground and doesn't print the one in the onPostExecute

Comment: Do you mean that your App crashes? If so, provide your stack trace.

Comment: Start the `AsyncTask` on ui thread

Comment: Just leave that poor `HttpUrlConnection` and `AsynckTask` and let the library handle everything itself. Use OkHttp, https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes (or at least provide stacktrace so we can see what is wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                                    

Process: com.example.stage.drawlayoutproject, PID: 31566
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
java.lang.String[] java.lang.String.split(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.example.stage.drawlayoutproject.Log_in$1.onClick(Log_in.java:87)  
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5254
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21174)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)    
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6862)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Looks like that 'connection' is a instance of `AsyncTask`. Not the `HttpAsync`.
In that case you should change the type of `connection` to `HttpAsync` or fill generic parameters for `connection` when you declare this field.

Comment: Actually I think that the FATAL EXCEPTION is dude to the fact that somehow I can't retrive the String from the AsyncTask so the split function is trying to divede an empty String. I still thinking that the onPostExecute is not called because I don't get the log message I putted inside in my stacktrace.

Comment: You are right! It's not called. You need to fix this exception first. And it will be called when you fix it!